# Updating play services without reducing minSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I use the following play services library in my android project. `play-services-location`,`play-services-auth` and `play-services-gcm`. The library are in version `9.2.0`.I have the `minSdkVersion` as `9`.

I recently added the `VerifyApps` API into the project and in order to use that library properly I had to add a new dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.6.0`. When I added it, android studio asked to enter some class paths in my`AndroidManifest` file or else I had to improve my `minSdkVersion` to `14`. After adding it some of the functionalities provided by the `auth`API started acting up throwing some runtime exceptions in devices running Android 5.0 and above.

I upgraded my `Auth` and `GCM` API to version `11.6.0`. Android studio again asked me to enter some more class paths in `AndroidManifest` file. After this the app is working fine but I came across this [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_version_102). According to this doc if I am using a `play-service` version greater than 10.2, my app will not work on devices below 4.0 (Correct me if I am wrong, But a careful look at the wordings lead me to believe that only the support is stopped but existing API calls will work just fine). But I am not using the full `play-service` dependency in my project I am just the aforementioned 4 libraries, so by adding the suggested entries in the `AndroidManifest` files should let my app to work just fine in devices below version 4.0 right?

If the functionalities are not fully supported then, is there a list of functionalities that will be affected by upgrading to this version?

Comment: The minimum version requirement of Android version 14 started with  Google Play services 10.2 release. To use Google Play 10.2.x and above, the [minimum Android API level must be 14 onwards](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_27_2017_-_version_1162).

Comment: @noogui I have already looked at the doc. My question is I am not importing `play-services` as a whole. I am only using some sub modules so does this apply to me or not is the question.

Comment: your error shows that it applies to you else you wouldnt run to these bumps.

Comment: Are you sure you need to support devices below 4.0? There are about 0.5% of users who are still below it: https://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a special flavor for older platforms, and use it with an older version of **gms**. You will deploy the two flavors as split APKs to Play Store.